# How to fix "GET css/app.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)"?

Tags: laravel, nginx

Installed php-fpm and nginx.
The site opens, but the CSS does not want to load.
Tell me how to solve the problem?

```
server {
    listen   80 default_server;

    root /var/www/public/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass phpfpm:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

UPDATE: interesting moment. I have a debugger installed and the css is loading from it.

```
/_debugbar/assets/stylesheets?v=1553506748
```

Comment: move the css file to the root directory

Comment: Why move it to the root directory?

Comment: because it can't find the css in public directory.

Comment: everything works at the local machine

Comment: Can you confirm that the file definitely exists on your remote machine? Can you also show the code where you're including the url.

Comment: I confirm that the file is in the folder /var/www/public/css/app.css

Comment: any luck on this @SergeyAndrianov?